# Shortest way to disable all forms autocomplete to off in a application. Not by adding autocomplete off to each form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

Want to disable autocomplete to off for each form in the application. But not by adding autocomplete off to each form in the application is there any other short way to disable forms autocomplete to off.

Comment: Maybe use javascript to run a loop on all forms?

Comment: The question makes no sense... you want to turn off the autocomplete setting, without changing the autocomplete setting?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I assume they mean "without adding the autocomplete="off" attribute to the HTML"

Answer (score 0):

As Tushar commented, you could loop over all the forms (or inputs) and set the autocomplete attribute to "off".

```
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input')
for (let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
  inputElements[i].autocomplete = 'off'
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(ele => ele.autocomplete = 'off')` is a lot shorter and faster

Comment: It is shorter, but not faster. The for loop is about 18% faster https://jsbench.me/x1kqm73x1i/1
forEach is more readable though, but isn't supported in IE.

Comment: forEach on forms will be faster than a for loop on all inputs. If you must support IE, wrap in spread: `[…document.querySelectorAll("form")].forEach`